# Missing GroupID in GroupsActivityDetail Report

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

From the Admin Center When I download the Group Activity Report, it gives the "Group Display Name" column which has name of the group. AFAIK name is not a unique property for Groups and two groups may have same name.

It's difficult to get information on group by name incase of identical names.

If report can provide groupID along with DisplayName, I think that would really help automating the process on getting further group information through Graph.

Can someone from MSFT provide info on this, if this is planned or there is any reason not to include?

Answer (score 0):

> If report can provide groupID along with DisplayName, I think that would really help automating the process on getting further group information through Graph.

We can submit a feature request on [the user voice](https://office365.uservoice.com/)

Comment: I did. Please vote for it. https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/36175189-groupid-in-groupactivitydetail-report